# TimThumb & htaccess : clean url

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, timthumb

Do you know if there's a way to alter via htaccess the **[timthumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/)** urls ?
My question is if i can change for example urls like this

thumb.php?src=http://mysite.com/images/image.jpg&h=200&w=350&zc=1&q=80

to

http://mysite.com/images/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Cadeyrn's code  work probably for 1 specific size ( 200&w=350& etc) , the major problem with timthumb and the reason people use it, is that it allows for many dynamic sizes thus making .htaccess rewrite rules much more difficult, especially if you using friendly WordPress permalink structure.

There is a guide here on how to do it, it might need tweaking and honestly timthumb should be avoided. http://revisedagain.com/?p=18

Comment: Good link, and you're actually right about the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the .htaccess file, and add some rewrite rules. This only works with apache2, for other web servers, you need other solution.

Before the main part of the wordpress rewrite rules, but after RewriteEngine On:

```
# check if the file exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ thumb.php?src=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1&h=200&w=350&zc=1&q=80 [L]
```

Please note, I cannot test this right now, and I'm really not sure, it'll work, but you need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this solution:

http://revisedagain.com/2011/custom-rewrite-rules-with-wordpress-timthumb/

from URL above:

This rule tells the server that

```
http://www.domain.com/resize/160×130/r/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/pic.jpg
```

should be interpreted as

```
http://www.domain.com/resize/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/pic.jpg&h=130&w=160&c=1
```

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.